# Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core (File Upload)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Following the guide from https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1 I encountered strange behaviour.

I call some ASP.NET web-apis from an ASP.NET Core MVC App.

I added the following lines of code to my Startup.cs:

```
readonly string MicroserviceOrigins = "MicroserviceOrigins";

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: MicroserviceOrigins,builder =>{builder.AllowAnyOrigin();});
    });
...

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(MicroserviceOrigins);
...
```

All Code runs fine, Microservices get called and return [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 30ms].

But after the all OK response my PageInspectore console write errors like “Cross-Origin Request Blocked”
Where can these errors come from?
Did I mess up the AllowAnyOrigin Configuration or do I have to do similar configuration inside my ASP.Net web-api?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Edit:
minimal workable project ASP.NET Core Web-Api Project:
startup.cs:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: "ServiceOrigin", builder => { builder.AllowAnyOrigin(); });
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("ServiceOrigin");

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me File Upload</button>

<div style="display: none;">
    <form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/*" name="uploadImage">
        <input type="text" id="File_TestEntityID" />
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction(){
        document.getElementById("uploadImage").click();
    }

    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#uploadImage").on('change', (function (e) {

            var fileInput = document.getElementById('uploadImage');
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('uploadImage', file);
            FileUpload(formData, Callback);
        }));
    });

    function FileUpload(formData, callbackfn) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:63993/api/fileupload?TestEntityID=SampleFolder",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                callbackfn(data);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                callbackfn(e);
            }
        });
    }
    function Callback(data) {
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is `RDDSMicroserviceOrigins`?

Comment: @Vernou sorry copy paste error, i fixed it.

Comment: Can you share your code in App?

Comment: You need to add readonly string ServiceOrigin= "ServiceOrigin"; in your web api project start up.

Comment: @Yiyi You I provided a minimal index.cshtml and startup.cs in question which upload a file to a local version of this web api https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/uploading-a-file-in-Asp-Net-web-api/

Comment: Replace `contentType: false,` by `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',`

Comment: @Vernou get still the same error : /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add similar configuration to my web-api or in my case since it was asp.net (not core).
I had to install

> System.Web.Http.Cors

and add something like the following to my Controller:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

and inside WebApiConfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.EnableCors();
    ...
}
```

I did not find any guide on why I had to do this. But I imagine it has to do that my test case as file upload which had communications both ways? I was just confused since the error looked like it happened on Clint side JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
           options.AddPolicy(name: "ServiceOrigin", builder => { 
          builder.AllowAnyOrigin(); });
            });
```

try this

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy( "ServiceOrigin", builder =>
    {
     builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
     .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```